# Android Dynamically add multiple data to list?

Tags: android

Here is my code.It's working fine for single data,but i don't know about changes that i should make to make it work for more data.
  for example when user add name and number it  should display 
 both data.

![enter image description here][1]

ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.attndence);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);



    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                      edit.setText("");
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Come on .... you are not adding the number value how it will show ?

Comment: ya but when i add it it displayed as next row in list ,not in single row

Comment: EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
                list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                //list1.add(edit1.getText().toString());
                edit.setText("");
                edit1.setText("");
                
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both in one row then add little bit like this :

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name); 
EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number); 
String numbAndNo = edit.getText().toString() +"     "+edit1.getText().toString();
list.add(numAndNo);
edit.setText("");
edit1.setText("");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```